# How do I change confidence interval calculation to log-log on R?

Tags: r, survival-analysis, confidence-interval, hazard

If I wanted to calculate confidence intervals using the coxph and confinf functions, how do I change the confidence interval calculation to log-log? My understanding is that log is the default.

I tried `conf.type="log-log"` but it did not work, just got an error message

```
library(survival) 

coxph(formula = Surv(futime, fustat) ~ tx, data = tki, conf.type="log-log") 

fit <- coxph(formula = Surv(futime, fustat) ~ tx, data = tki)

summary(fit) 

#output provides HR CIs 
confint(fit) 

#coefficient CIs 
exp(confint(fit)) 

> dput(tki) structure(list(futime = c(9.26, 11.06, 2.35, 3.75, 12.4, 10.3,  8.11, 7.29, 6.75, 6.56, 0.26, 1.9, 0.34, 1.63, 1.55, 1.6, 4.78,  2.65, 1.72, 3.63), fustat = c(1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1,  1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1), tx = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1,  1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2)), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl",  "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -20L))
```

Comment: Could you please share some code you have tried with reproducible data using `dput`? So we can help you better.

Comment: library(survival)

coxph(formula = Surv(futime, fustat) ~ tx, data = tki, conf.type="log-log")

fit <- coxph(formula = Surv(futime, fustat) ~ tx, data = tki)

summary(fit)

#output provides HR CIs
confint(fit) 

#coefficient CIs
exp(confint(fit))

Comment: > dput(tki)
structure(list(futime = c(9.26, 11.06, 2.35, 3.75, 12.4, 10.3, 
8.11, 7.29, 6.75, 6.56, 0.26, 1.9, 0.34, 1.63, 1.55, 1.6, 4.78, 
2.65, 1.72, 3.63), fustat = c(1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1), tx = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2)), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", 
"data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -20L))

Comment: You may want to use `survfit(fit, conf.type = "log-log")`?

Comment: The confidence interval is still the same regardless of that code. Maybe I'm not using it correctly? Is there something from my initial code that I should replace using  survfit(fit, conf.type = "log-log")?

Comment: The error seems rather informative "Argument conf.type not matched". and looking at the help page `?coxph` it come as no surprise that there is no 'conf.type' argument documented.

Answer (score 1):

The log(-log()) method of producing confidence intervals applies to the estimates of survival probabilities (or related transformations). We need to use the `survfit()` function to create those, `confint()` will not work. The default method is `log` as you note. Supplying `conf.type = "log-log"` changes the method as desired.

Note however, that the use of `survfit()` with a `coxph()` model almost always requires you to correctly specify the `newdata =` option. See the details in `?survfit.coxph`. Ignoring this will usually still give you some result, but it will be wrong in subtle ways.

```r
library(survival) 
tki = structure(list(
  futime = c(9.26, 11.06, 2.35, 3.75, 12.4, 10.3,  8.11, 7.29, 6.75, 
             6.56, 0.26, 1.9, 0.34, 1.63, 1.55, 1.6, 4.78,  2.65, 1.72, 3.63), 
  fustat = c(1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1,  1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1), 
  tx = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1,  1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2)), 
  class = c("tbl_df", "tbl",  "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -20L)) 
coxmod <- coxph(Surv(futime, fustat) ~ tx, data = tki)
summary(coxmod)
#> Call:
#> coxph(formula = Surv(futime, fustat) ~ tx, data = tki)
#> 
#>   n= 20, number of events= 11 
#> 
#>      coef exp(coef) se(coef)     z Pr(>|z|)   
#> tx 2.2783    9.7599   0.8335 2.733  0.00627 **
#> ---
#> Signif. codes:  0 '***' 0.001 '**' 0.01 '*' 0.05 '.' 0.1 ' ' 1
#> 
#>    exp(coef) exp(-coef) lower .95 upper .95
#> tx      9.76     0.1025     1.905        50
#> 
#> Concordance= 0.744  (se = 0.042 )
#> Likelihood ratio test= 9.41  on 1 df,   p=0.002
#> Wald test            = 7.47  on 1 df,   p=0.006
#> Score (logrank) test = 10.34  on 1 df,   p=0.001
confint(coxmod) #confint provides confidence interval for coefficient estimate
#>       2.5 %   97.5 %
#> tx 0.644588 3.911983
exp(confint(coxmod)) #confidence interval for hazard ratio
#>       2.5 %   97.5 %
#> tx 1.905202 49.99797

# We need to define 'newdata' to use in survfit, include all covariates.
# If you don't use newdata, the results are almost certainly not what you want.
newdat = data.frame(tx = c(1, 2))

# Fit model for survival function using survfit. Set confidence interval type
survmod <- survfit(coxmod, newdata = newdat, conf.type = "log-log")

# Upper and lower confidence intervals for survival probability, 1 column
# for each row of newdata.
survmod$upper
#>               1         2
#>  [1,] 0.9992040 0.9873779
#>  [2,] 0.9974256 0.9539678
#>  [3,] 0.9974256 0.9539678
#>  ...
survmod$lower
#>               1            2
#>  [1,] 0.8972081 5.232360e-01
#>  [2,] 0.8626622 4.631231e-01
#>  [3,] 0.8626622 4.631231e-01
#>  ...
plot(survmod, conf.int = T, col = c("red","blue"))
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2023-02-21 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

---

Reply to comment:

> is there a way to simply generate a hazard ratio and a 95% confidence interval calculated with the log-log method?

I think you have misunderstood something about how confidence intervals are calculated and what the different methods are estimating.

By default, `coxph()` estimates the variance of the parameters using the inverse of the information matrix. An alternative is to use a "robust" variance estimate by entering `robust = TRUE` in the `coxph()` call. (The robust estimate uses an infintisimal jackknife, see 2.7 of the package documentation vignette, https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/survival/vignettes/survival.pdf .) The `confint()` function then uses the estimated variance to construct a "wald-type" confidence interval for the parameter estimates. Finally, taking the `exp()` of the confidence interval for the parameter estimate gives a confidence interval for the hazard ratio. (The code included in the question seems to have a mistake in labeling the confidence intervals. But, you can see the result matches `summary(fit)`.)

At no point in the above calculations was a log or a log-log confidence interval used or available. If you try to include a `conf.type =` option in the `coxph()` call then it gives an error and refuses to run.

The log method of calculating confidence intervals is the default for the `survfit()` function. By specifying `conf.type =` option in the `survfit()` function you can change the method used from "log" to any of the supported options: "log", "log-log", "plain", "none", "logit", or "arcsin". `survfit()` uses these methods to calculate a confidence interval for the survival probability. `survfit()` does not estimate the hazard ratio, it bases the estimate of the survival probability off of the hazard ratio that was estimated by `coxph()`.

Comment: Thank you, but is there a way to simply generate a hazard ratio and a 95% confidence interval calculated with the log-log method? I was generating a hazard ratio and 95% CI with the log method with the code I used in my initial post, I just want to convert it to log-log.

Comment: @Rproject I edited a response into the answer. I think you've misunderstood something about the confidence interval calculation. Is there something you read which told you a log-log confidence interval was an option for the hazard ratio?